# Memory management how to fix leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm building a statistics monitor application and I'm using a XML parser to retrieve my data.
After a lot of research, learning and reading about the memory management and retainCount, etc. of obj-c but I still encounter memory leaks in Instruments.

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) { //Loop trough the childs
        //Instruments Leaks tells me that I have 75% leaks here
        [entryItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
    }

    //Instruments Leaks tells me that I have 25% leaks here
    [totalEntries addObject:[entryItem copy]]; //Copy it into the MutableArray
```

The memory leaks occur in the XML parser but I don't know how to fix the leak.

```
- (NSString *)stringValue {
if (_node->type == XML_TEXT_NODE || _node->type == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE){
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)_node->content]; //16.7% leaking
}

if (_node->type == XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE){
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)_node->children->content]; //50.0% leaking
}

NSMutableString *theStringValue = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
for (CXMLNode *child in [self children]) {
    [theStringValue appendString:[child stringValue]]; //33.3% leaking
}

return theStringValue;
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the line

```
[totalEntries addObject:[entryItem copy]];
```

you copy the object (hence your new object has a retain count of one), and add it to totalEntries, which again increases the retain count. You're missing a release. Should be

```
[totalEntries addObject:[[entryItem copy] autorelease]];
```

or

```
NSObject* copiedItem = [entryItem copy];
[totalEntries addObject:copiedItem];
[copiedItem release];
```

You can use the static analyzer to get some insight into this. And with ARC coming, you'll soon needn't worry about this at all (although it is useful to gain some understanding of it anyway).

Comment: Hmm I see I made a mistake in my example because I'm already releasing the entryItem under the addObject function. The problem really occurs to be in the second example I posted.

Comment: is totalEntries a custom object or a collection?

Comment: Remember that Instruments is telling you were a leak was allocated, not the extra `retain` that is causing it to leak....

Comment: @bbum i liked your instruments blog post by the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the complete details and all kind of possible leaks fixes here are the references:
http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/
http://www.slideshare.net/OwenGoss/finding-and-fixing-memory-leaks-in-ios-apps-5251292
http://maniacdev.com/2011/02/tutorial-debugging-objective-c-memory-leaks-for-beginners/
http://www.streamingcolour.com/blog/tutorials/tracking-iphone-memory-leaks/
http://dandesousa.com/2011/02/11/how-to-fix-ios-memory-leaks-coming-from-uikit/

Comment: +1 With the exception of the one which gives dubious advice, these are a nice collection of links. Thanks for sharing.