# Changing View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've inheretate a project from other people. The thing is that the code has the `setViewController` method that is inside the AppDelegate to change among views. The problem is that this code seems to leak memory BIG TIME. I've been trying to fix the code, but I can't seem to get that right. What would you think it's the best solution? to fix this code  or to use a Navigation Controller all together instead?

```
// The Code to change the views
- (void)setViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:_window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void) 
     {
         BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
         [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
         _window.rootViewController = viewController;
         [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
     } 
                    completion:nil];

}

// The calls to the setViewController
-(void) gotoHowToUseView{
    [self setViewController:[[[HowToVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HowToVC" bundle:nil] autorelease]];
}
-(void) gotoHowToCredits{
    [self setViewController:[[[CreditsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreditsVC" bundle:nil] autorelease]];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is here, and not in the failure of the controllers' to clean up after themselves in `dealloc`? Have you run the code through the static analyzer (shift-command-B)? Have you run it through the instrument's leaks tool?

Comment: By the way, while I prefer other ways to navigate between controllers rather than replacing the `rootViewController`, if I'm correct that the problem does not rest in the above code, but rather somewhere else (e.g. leaks, retain cycles, logic errors, sloppy cache usage such as `imageNamed`, etc), it's worth noting that shifting to another controller transitioning pattern, such as a navigation controller, will probably not solve your leak problem.

Comment: The static analyzer (shift-command-B) is great at finding basic leaks. For references on how to use Instruments to find the more challenging bugs, see the [Instruments Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4) on how to use it to find leaks. Or refer to this for a bunch of independent tutorials on finding leaks http://stackoverflow.com/a/7805117/1271826.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use UINavigation Controller.

Now sloution for your code is remove autorelease from both function. Add this two lines to setViewController function

```
  _window.rootViewController = nil;  // add this line
  _window.rootViewController = viewController; 
  [viewController release]; // add this line
```

Comment: here once referene given so it is better to relase rather than autorelease, so i told him to remove auto release

Comment: No offense, but I don't think replacing `autorelease` with `release` is likely to solve the problem. That just controls when the `release` takes place, not whether the `release` takes place. As a matter of programming style, I'm with you insofar as when I did non-ARC, I generally liked to manually `release` precisely at the earliest possible moment, much like you've advised, but in this case, where the alloc is happening in some other method, I'd probably lean towards `autorelease` anyway (otherwise it's easy to get unbalanced `alloc` and `release` statements). Either way, this isn't his leak.

Comment: Hi @Prince thank you for your code but sadly it didn't seem to fix it. I'm still getting reports (from both analyze and Instruments) of those view leaking memory. I think that the solution will be to use a Navigation Controller. What do you think @robert-ryan? Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @IgnacioOroná I'm not sure I'd go through that as I'm not convinced the problem is in the above code. It seems like an unusual construct, but regardless I'm not quite sure how you concluded that this was the source of the problem in the first place. I'd first fix any problems reported in the static analysis (shift-command-B). You should always have _zero_ warnings there. If you have any warnings you can't fix, you should post them there and we can try to help you out.